# Does Ada Wong's Level 1 ability trigger Infected text?

Tags: resident-evil-deck-building-game

In the Resident Evil Deck Building Game (base set), Ada Wong's level 1 ability allows her to look at the first card in the Mansion and choose to leave it on top or move it to the bottom. It is unclear whether the effect of the Infected would be applied or not, given that there is no actual combat.

Most of the effect text is obviously inconsequential; the Infected is neither defeated nor revealed so none of the effect text that triggers on defeat or reveal would apply anyway.  However, the Hunter and the Uroboros Aheri cards in the base set both trigger when the Infected in question is **not defeated**.

In particular, the text on the Uroboros Aheri card reads:

> If this Infected was not defeated, shuffle it into the Mansion

Although Ada's ability doesn't actually "defeat" anything, it's unclear whether the effect text applies at all.  If the card is placed on the bottom of the Mansion and the effect text is skipped entirely, that makes this the only way to guarantee the position of the Uroboros Aheri card without triggering a reshuffle, which just feels wrong to me.

So the question lies: **Does Ada's ability bypass the Infected card entirely, effects and all, or would the effects still trigger (when applicable)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ada Wong's ability allows her to look at the top card of the mansion deck, and either leave it on top, or place it on the bottom of the mansion deck. Although the rule book is unclear about a lot of aspects of the game, I don't think it is unclear what to do about Infected with Effects. The rules say that if an infected is revealed and it has an effect, take note of it, and apply it when the effect says so. Ada Wong's ability allows her to look at the card, not reveal it (a specific game term, that would make the top card open information), so no effects are triggered. I can also be determined from the rules, that only after revealing the top card of the mansion that you either defeat the infected and add it as a decoration to your character, or not defeat it is placed on the bottom of the mansion deck. So, any infected effects that trigger on not being defeated would only do so after being revealed.